socket.io - io.to(room) doesn't seem to work
for some reason socket.io won't send a message to a specific room.
right before using the io.to(${socket.id}-devices).emit("event", data)
i check what sockets are in said room by using: io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(${socket.id}-devices)
this returns 2 other sockets which is correct, but when I actually emit the event the other sockets don't receive anything. I use the exact same line of code just a different roomname(${socket.sessionId}) which works perfectly fine.
this is my current test setup with the code:
console.log( "other devices in room: ", io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(${socket.id}-devices`)
);
io.to(`${socket.id}-devices`).emit("signRequesttoRoom", data);
io.to(socket.sessionId).emit("signRequestothertest", data);
socket.in(`${socket.id}-devices`).emit("signRequestLetsTryThis", data);
socket.broadcast.emit("signRequestBR", data);`

the console output is the following:
other devices in room:  Set(3) { 'kdnswgpje', 'scanner-x6d3ae', 'secondscreen-u73ir2' }
kdnswgpje is the sending socket the roomname in this case is 'kdnswgpje-devices'
kdnswgpje recieves: signRequesttoRoom and signRequestothertest
scanner-x6d3ae receives: signRequestBR
secondscreen-u73ir2 receives: signRequestBR
the "io.to(socket.sessionId).emit("signRequestothertest", data);" was a test to see if it would work in the otherroom this socket was connected to and that one works just fine and it gets the event.
I have tried using a normal socket.broadcast but this results in all the sockets connected getting the message, but I need to only send them to the sockets in the room.
I have tried using a diffent roomname without any hyphens and just letters and numbers this did not work.
I have tried using just a plain string for the room as I knew the name of it, this also did not work.
